# unable to bringup the openstack instance after power outage

Tags: redhat, openstack, reboot

I am running openstack server on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

```
openstack nova version: 13.1.2
openstack swift version: 2.7.1
```

I have two instance which was running fine from 6 months.
The image from which these instances were launched had been deleted about 3 months back to release some space in the host machine. Even then i was able to reboot the instances without any issue.

Last week there was a power outage on the HOST machine and after it came up, these two isntance are in Error state. I am  not able to boot them up, wether as the right user or as admin

```
[root@duldoos ~(keystone_admin)]# nova reboot --poll 601e6328-7048-4b15-9933-bb8b9355a84f 
Cannot 'reboot' instance 601e6328-7048-4b15-9933-bb8b9355a84f while it is in vm_state error (HTTP 409) (Request-ID: req-89977b41-bec8-48ce-b80c-934f9c240e7d) 
ERROR (CommandError): Unable to reboot the specified server(s). 

[root@duldoos ~(keystone_admin)]# nova reboot --hard --poll 601e6328-7048-4b15-9933-bb8b9355a84f Request to reboot server <Server: dsc-1> has been accepted.


Error rebooting server

ERROR (CommandError): Wait for specified server(s) failed.
```

Its showing following on the admin page of the instance

```
Message
    Image d6384be5-7187-4efa-b835-de8e6bc06a01 could not be found.
Code
    404
```

I would like to bring these machines up with out losing data from these instances. Please let me know if i need to provide any more info

Comment: A workaround may be to `nova reset-state --active UUID-of-instance` then try rebooting it. If that still doesn't work then you'll want to check out the nova-compute.log file. Search for the UUID of the instance in the nova-compute.log file to see if there are additional error messages. If the nova logs aren't helpful then you can check on the VM in virsh. Using `nova show UUID` as an admin should show the ID for the VM used in virsh. At this point you'd also want to check the libvirt logs.